# How to add an brother element in zend framework Using Zend_Form_Element

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

For example:

```
$assignment_type = $this->createMyElement('text', 'assignment_type', array(
            'name' => 'assignment_type',
            'id' => 'assignment_type_label'
        ))->setAttrib('maxlength', '100')->addDecorator('Htmltag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'input_text'));
```

Here I am creating an input wraped by div tag, but how can I add other element inside this div?

So I want to see something like this:

```
<div>
<input />
<img /> <!--the brother element created -->

</div>
```

Is that possible? or what hacks I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it to wrap three elements in one div (a date picker in this case):

```
$bday = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('bday');
        $bday->setLabel('Birth Date: ')
             ->setDecorators(array(
                 array('ViewHelper'),
                 array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
                 array('HtmlTag', //opening tag
                     array(
                         'tag'       => 'div',
                         'openOnly'  => TRUE,
                         'id'        => 'bday',
                         'placement' => 'prepend'
                 )),
             ));
        $bdaymonth = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('bdaymonth');
        $bdaymonth->addValidator('Digits')
                  ->setDecorators(array(
                      array('ViewHelper')
                  ));

        $bdayyear = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('bdayyear');
        $bdayyear->addValidator('Digits')
                 ->setDecorators(array(
                     array('ViewHelper'),
                     array('HtmlTag', //closing tag
                         array(
                             'tag'       => 'div',
                             'closeOnly' => TRUE
                     )),
                 )); //elements truncated for brevity
```

I hope this gives you some ideas.